# UITableViewCell background image not always showing

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am setting my table view background using an image:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"]] autorelease];
```

I use the table to show content from a REST API, at the beginning when I am waiting for the result I set the number of rows to 5 and then when the results arrive I set the right number of cells. My problem is whenever the number of results is smaller than 5 the background image is set only for the results cells and the others are white.

The rest of the cells are set without cellForRowAtIndexPath being called. Where are they coming from?

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Are u upset with empty cells appearing or are u upset with no background for the empty cells? What is your exact question and as @jbat100 has already commented, POST YOUR cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`cell.backgroundView.contentView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"]] autorelease];`

Answer (score -1):

do the following

```
willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSindexPath *)indexpath
{
  cell.backgroundview = view;
 }
```

now it will work

Answer (score -4):

Try to remove the autorelease from the code

Comment: That is not the problem, backgroundView is retained so it should be released, since there is an alloc.

Comment: cell.backgroundView is a retain property, not autoreleasing would create a leak.

Comment: eventually I just set the number of rows to be 5 when I get less than 5 results. This solved the problem.